# Screen tearing while using gnome and not while using unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, gnome, i3-wm

Whenever I use a de or wm other than unity, like gnome or i3, i have screen tearing. I am using the nvidia proprietary driver. Any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

Fix screen tearing with Linux and NVIDIA 384 Driver:

In terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
```

in the file change:

```
options nvidia_384_drm modeset=0
```

to:

```
options nvidia_384_drm modeset=1
```

In terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot

Comment: Some will say to use pkexec gedit instead of sudo gedit but pkexec will likely return an error. sudo gedit gets the job done.

Comment: Did this, and my system wouldn't boot up until I started up in recovery mode and reverted the change.